# how to delete common data in two lookups in splunk and gain unique data in the table

Tags: duplicates, lookup, splunk

i have 2 lookup
look1 ip host status type
look 2 ip host
please help me for
how to delete common data in two lookups in splunk and gain unique data in the table
thank you

```
| inputlookup Misili_OA_Daily
  |search NOT  [|inputlookup Misili_OA_Changes
|format]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query looks close.  How is it failing you?

The key to using a subsearch is to make sure it returns fields present in the main search - otherwise, you'll get no results.

Assuming Misili_OA_Daily is look1 and Misili_OA_Changes is look2 then this may help.

```
| inputlookup Misili_OA_Daily where NOT [|inputlookup Misili_OA_Changes
  | fields ip host | format ]
```